# Programmatically count mongodb _id field

Tags: mongodb

I want to run my script to start from the field where it last ended. But I am unable to understand mongodb _id field.

- Is it possible to use incremental int as default id  (`_id`) in
  MongoDB? Just like SQL based AUTO_INCREMENT?
- Why is mongodb `_id` value such a long generated string? What does it represent? How do I count it programmatically? What kind of algorithm does it use and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get last inserted _id as

```
db.col1.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
```

for your second point read this [read this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)